# Probability without replacement .

Tags: probability, combinatorics, permutations

Inside a candy jar, one can find 5 dark chocolates and 4 white chocolates. One after the other, every candy is taken out of the jar randomly and without replacement. If the chance of grabbing a dark chocolate is same as the white chocolate, what is the probability that the 6th chocolate is not dark ?

Options are:

1. 1/3
2. 2/3
3. 4/9
4. 7/9
5. 8/9

I tried to list all the possible scenarios and came with an answer 7/9(Which is probably incorrect) but I am very new to permutation and combinations. So if anyone can provide an explanation on how the process actually works  will be very much appreciated

Comment: How did you come up with that answer?

Comment: First of all, chance of picking a dark chocolate cannot be same as white chocolate, badly phrased question. Second, what probability do you get that the first is not dark and what info do you have that changes that answer to $7/9$ for 6th pick?

Comment: I wrote cases like 5 dark followed by 4 white . Then 3 dark followed by white then dark .. and so on . After that I added all  the cases .

Comment: How should we approach this question ?

Comment: Do you think the probability will change from first pick to second to .. sixth? Why should it change?

Comment: It will remain the same ?

Comment: Yes it should. You can do all the complicated calculation to show in the end that they would remain the same. If you are still not convinced, I would suggest you go by expected number of remaining dark and white chocolates after every pick. See what happens for second pick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It’s best to work by cases based on the number of whites drawn till the $5$th draw.

$0$ whites: Then you need $BBBBBW$, which has probability $$\frac 59 \frac 48 \frac 37 \frac 26 \frac 15 \frac 44 $$

$1$ white: You need to arrange $4$ $B$’s and $1$ $W$ followed by $1$ white and you’ll see all the arrangements are equally likely. Multiply this probability with the number of ways of arranging: $$\frac 59 \frac 48 \frac 37 \frac 26 \frac 45 \frac 34  \times {5\choose 1 }$$

$2$ whites: This case is very similar. You need to arrange $3$ blacks and $2$ whites. $$\frac 59 \frac 48 \frac 37 \frac 46 \frac 35 \frac 24 \times {5\choose 2}$$

$3$ whites: $$\frac 59 \frac 48 \frac 47 \frac 36 \frac 25 \frac 14 \times {5\choose 3} $$

You cannot have more than $3$ whites, as then you’ll run out of whites. The required probability $(4/9)$ is obtained by adding up these probabilities.

Comment: Why we are multiplying combinations at the end since 1 white ?

Comment: @akshatnayak Because say for $2$ whites, any of the permutations of $B,B,B,W,W$ work.

Comment: Can you recommend me any resource to look at ? @Tavish . I think I need much more work in this topic ,

Comment: @akshatnayak [Brilliant.org](https://brilliant.org/discrete-mathematics/) makes for some nice practice.